# Redirecting to Storyboard if not Authenticated

Tags: swift, storyboard, facebook-login

Im new to iOS but familiar with Android and currently working with open source VLC media player code.

What i want to do is add a redirect to a login screen if the user opens app and isnt logged in through Facebook

```
if AccessToken.current != nil {
            // basic usage
            self.view.makeToast("Logged In")

        }else {
            // basic usage
            self.view.makeToast("Logged Out")

          // Add redirect to login page logic here

        }
```

How do i create a login page and redirect?

Ive created a storyboard called LoginScreen.storyboard and added some buttons and i would like to redirect to that if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First give the ViewController that you've created a **Storyboard ID** from the Interface Builder by clicking on your ViewController -> Identity Inspector. After assigning an ID to your VC, in your code:

```
if AccessToken.current != nil {
        // TODO
        self.view.makeToast("Logged In")

    }else {
        self.view.makeToast("Logged Out")

      let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "LoginScreen", bundle: nil) // current Storyboard
      let loginVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifierName") // instantiate Login page
      self.present(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil) // present instantiated ViewController

    }
```

Comment: Im not sure where to click on the View Controller. Is it in the GUI when you click on the storyboard file?

Comment: @ChrisM Open main.storyboard from the left navigation tab, you will see a white bar above your view controller. Click it, then at the top of the right menu you'll be able to navigate to Identity Inspector.

Comment: I have no main.storyboard file and this is why i cant follow tutorials. Im using https://github.com/videolan/vlc-ios

Comment: @ChrisM Select the one you created then, LoginScreen.storyboard as i understand. Then follow the steps above.

Comment: I found StoryBoard ID section on the right of the editor and entered "LoginScreenFacebook"

Comment: Then change "yourIdentifierName" with that in the code i wrote.

Comment: Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'LoginScreen' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

Comment: Click the view controller as you did before, again in the right menu, go to "Attributes Inspector" and check the box named "Is Initial View Controller" and run again.

Comment: That seems like its working there now. Very much appreciated for the help.

Comment: @ChrisM If you don't want your app to start from that viewcontroller you can check another one as Initial ViewController. No problem, gl.